# HQL update query

Tags: hql

I've got problem to exceute one update-HQL-query.

I want to edit values saved in profile entity, but with no luck.

my entities looks like below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", catalog = "testdb")
public class UserEntity implements java.io.Serializable {

private Integer id;
private String username;
private String password;
private Profile profile;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public Profile getProfile() {
    return this.profile;
}

public void setProfile(Profile profile) {
    this.profile = profile;
}
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "profiles", catalog = "testdb")
public class Profile implements java.io.Serializable {
private Integer id;
private UserEntity user;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
public UserEntity getUser() {
    return this.user;
}

public void setUser(UserEntity user) {
    this.user = user;
}
}
```

In controller I want to execute the following update query:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/profile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String profilePost(ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute("user") UserEntity user) {

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

session.beginTransaction();

Query query = session.createQuery("update UserEntity u set u.profile.firstName =     :firstName"
                    + " where u.username = :username");

query.setParameter("firstname", "john");
query.setParameter("username", user.getUsername());
int result = query.executeUpdate();

session.getTransaction().commit();

return "redirect:/login";
}
```

could You give me some advice how should lok this query:)?

Answer (score 4):

From [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#batch-direct):

> There can only be a single entity named in the from-clause. It can,
>   however, be aliased. If the entity name is aliased, then any property
>   references must be qualified using that alias. If the entity name is
>   not aliased, then it is illegal for any property references to be
>   qualified.
>
> No joins, either implicit or explicit, can be specified in a bulk HQL
>   query. Sub-queries can be used in the where-clause, where the
>   subqueries themselves may contain joins.

The idea of an ORM like Hibernate is to avoid such update queries. You get a persistent entity from the session, you modify it, and Hibernate transparently saves the updates to the database:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select p from Profile p where p.user.username = :username");
Profile p = query.setString("username", user.getUsername()).uniqueResult();
p.setFirstName("john");
```