# hql update query for one property

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am faced with very strange problem, and can't find a way to resolve it. I wrote the following HQL in intellij's HQL Console

```
update NewsEntity ne set ne.main=false where ne.main=true
```

StackTrace

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!
 at org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.NodeTraverser.traverseDepthFirst(NodeTraverser.java:31)
 at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:254)
 at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:157)
 at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:111)
 at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
 at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:56)
 at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:72)
 at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:133)
 at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:112)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1623)
 in RemoteSessionImpl.createQuery(RemoteSessionImpl.java:50)
 in RemoteUtil.executeWithClassLoader(RemoteUtil.java:122)
 in RemoteUtil$2$1.invoke(RemoteUtil.java:81)
 in HibernateEngine.createQuery(HibernateEngine.java:142)
```

When I write a `delete` query I don't have the same problem.

I have based this query around the following article [HQL update query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656993/hql-update-query). But, can't seem to figure out why I am still having this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of an ORM like `Hibernate` is to avoid such update queries.
You've just to load the object from the db, change the field and then `Hibernate` will update the object for out.

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from NewsEntity ne where ne.main = true");
NewsEntity newsEntity = (NewsEntity) query.uniqueResult();
newsEntity.setMain=false;
//Hibernate will update the object
```

If there're more objects:

```
List<NewsEntity> newsEntities = (List<NewsEntity>) query.list();
for(NewsEntity entity : newsEntities)
{
 entity.setMain=false;
}
```

Hibernate also supports DML statements, so to do an `update` query you should do:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("your update query");
int result = query.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: @Antropo OK. But I have not uniqueResult. All records in this table except one aren't main. I cant believe that if I want to change one property for all records. I should get records, change property for every in loop and save

Comment: Change `uniqueResult()` with `list()` and update all objects in a loop.

Comment: @Antropo I understand that if I have list, I change property in loop OK, but it means that instead of assign this task on db I do it manually and in loop. It takes more time then simple query in db. If I have 10000 records ...

Comment: I updated the answer, check the [manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-direct) for bulk updates in HQL